# Cannot use a scalar value as an array - PHP Octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, twig, octobercms

I had this working before but no it doesn't.  I have an array in my model, In a component I call the array and try to set as a page variable but it refuses to have it.

Model - Profile.php

```
public static $ajaxSortingOptions = array(
        'count_views desc' => 'Most Popular',
        'count_photos desc' => 'Most Photos',
        'count_videos desc' => 'Most Videos',
        'created_at desc' => 'Recent Members',
        'random' => 'Random'
    );
```

Component - Profiles.php

```
public $sortingOptions;

public function getAjaxSortOrderOptions()
    {
        return Profile::$ajaxSortingOptions;
    }

public function onRun()
    {   

        $this->listProfiles();

        $this->page['sortingOptions'] = $this->getAjaxSortOrderOptions();

    }
```

and in my view

```
<select class="dropdown" name="Filter[sort]">
                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        {% for key,value in sortingOptions  %}
                                            <option value="{{key}}">{{ value }}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
```

Cannot use a scalar value as an array

```
/var/www/public/plugins/libre/membership/components/Profiles.php line 147
```

the line in question

```
$this->page['sortingOptions'] = $this->getAjaxSortOrderOptions();
```

Comment: I don't know laravel but `sortingOptions` !== `sortOptions`

Comment: just edited and updated my code.  Still the same error but thanks for spotting that

Comment: `$this->page` is probably an integer.

Comment: It means that `$this->page` has previously been set to something other than an array.

Comment: Thanks yes I have a $this->page which is prob interfering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this simple test example:

```
class foo{

    protected $page=1;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->page['bar'] = 'hello';
    }

}

new foo;
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2122ee3e65506e37e11bea674560ea52394f76c8)

Output

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot use a scalar value as an array in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

I just wanted to put this in here, so the answer is an acutal answer.

> Thanks, I had this bit of code in `$this->page = $this->page['page'] = $this->profiles->currentPage();` somewhere else

As I said in the comments it's very easy to do things like this as they are valid at the time.  Much like using `=` in place of `==` it can be really hard to spot the bug only the cascade effect it causes.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I had this bit of code in $this->page = $this->page['page'] = $this->profiles->currentPage();  somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.   it's easy to do things like that, which are perfectly valid at the time.  such as using assignment (=) instead of comparison (==) they can be hard to spot, glad you found it.